# Will there be memory management issue by instantiating UITableViewCell using class method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
    extension SettingsTableViewController {
         override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
             let cell = SettingsTableViewCell.getSettingTableViewCell(tableview: tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
             return cell
         }
    }
    class SettingsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
         static let identifier = "SettingsTableViewCell"
         public class func getSettingTableViewCell(tableview: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> SettingsTableViewCell {
             if let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SettingsTableViewCell {
                 return cell
             }
             return SettingsTableViewCell()
         }
     }
```

By instantiating a tableView Cell with this approach. Are we going to face any memory management related issue?

Comment: No, but what is the benefit of this code? And why don't you force unwrap the cell in its own class?

Comment: Trying to keep TableViewCell related code in respective file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.

You don't need to do that manually when you register your cell class with the tableview, however:

```
// e.g. in viewDidLoad
tableView.register(SettingsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```